# Spring JPA Mysql json_set boolean saving as 1/0

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

Currently we have a table with a column in json datatype. That stores

```
{
    "newTicketLowInd": false,
    "newTicketHighInd": false,
    "newTicketMediumInd": false,
    "newTicketUrgentInd": false,
    "becomeTicketOwnerInd": false
}
```

and I wanted to add a new element with default value of `true`. Thus

```
@Modifying
@Query("update UserSettings u set u.jsonCol = json_set(u.jsonCol , '$.newElement', :indicator)")
void bulkUpdateTicketConversationUpdateMyselfInd(@Param("indicator") boolean indicator);
```

Or in MySQL

```
update UserSettings u set u.jsonCol = json_set(u.jsonCol , '$.newElement', true)
```

But it is storing `boolean` value as 1/0.

```
{
    "newTicketLowInd": false,
    "newTicketHighInd": false,
    "newTicketMediumInd": false,
    "newTicketUrgentInd": false,
    "becomeTicketOwnerInd": false,
    "newElement": 1
}
```

How can I store it as `true` or `false`? the same as the current elements stored.

Answer (score 0):

I just used nativeQuery in jpa

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "update user u set u.email_notification_settings = json_set(u.email_notification_settings, '$.ticketConversationUpdateMyselfInd', true)")
```